# Exclude duplicate elements with lower priority (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have the following model:

```
class Action(BaseModel):
    action_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, db_index=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    object = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    priority = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Suppose there are two 4 objects:

```
{"action_id":1, "name":"read", "object":"post", "priority":1}
{"action_id":2, "name":"write", "object":"post", "priority":2}
{"action_id":3, "name":"read", "object":"user", "priority":1}
{"action_id":4, "name":"update", "object":"user", "priority":2}
```

How can I filter out objects with the same `object` value, and leave only those with a `priority` higher in the duplicate set?

```
[{"action_id":2, "name":"write", "object":"post", "priority":2}, {"action_id":4, "name":"update", "object":"user", "priority":2}]
```

I tried filtering methods with - `annotate`, `Max`, `Count` and `filter` but duplicates are returned if i filter by *priority*

Comment: It would be better to include expected output in your question.

Comment: @Ahtisham: the expected output is at the bottom, only two of the `Action`s are retained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You filter out items if there is an item with the same `object`, but a higher precedence, so:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

Action.objects.filter(
    ~Exists(
        Action.objects.filter(
            object=OuterRef('object'), priority__gt=OuterRef('priority')
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: What is it transfered as raw query ?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM action WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT pk FROM action AS a WHERE a.object = action.object AND a.priority > action.priority)`

Comment: But thinking in terms of raw queries with Django is not very effective.

Comment: Why isn't it effective ? With raw query we get rid of ORM overhead. Morever ORM ultimately converts to raw query.

Comment: @Ahtisham: because the performance overhead is completely ineligible, this deals with a few CPU cycles, a queryset is dialect-invariant, allows flexible filtering that is still safe from SQL injection (since you can not pass the name of a field as SQL parameter that is a vulnerability that the ORM is supposed to protect against).

Comment: Yes I know ORM helps in SQL injection but ultimately if you are dealing with huge number of datasets raw query is the prefered way.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem first of all, thanks for the quick response) Secondly, the filtering works great, thanks!

Comment: @Ahtisham: no, you normally use a bulk insert/bulk update or something similar in that way. Constructing the query is a matter of nanoseconds, whereas insertion is a matter of milliseconds. That is not worth the overhead. It also conflicts with the idea of Python that programmer's convenience is more important than a few CPU cycles: Python does not get the last cycle out of a CPU, but makes programmer easier, and often that is less costly than buying a slightly stronger machine.

Comment: What about if you are having a huge query spanning multiple lines with various joins.

Comment: @Ahtisham: even then. The ORM is almost never the bottleneck. It is in essence some string processing. It requires some method calls and that, but converting it to a raw query itself does not open files, does not interact with the network, so it is only some CPU cycles, and this usually works in microseconds at most. The query itself on the other hand requires some network connection (or pipe with the process), which takes often *a lot* more time.

Comment: The ORM is not yet perfect, but unless some scenario is not covered by the ORM (and these become quite limited nowadays), the ORM is normally preferred over raw queries. Especially with for example `.prefetch_related` which will use two queries, but reduces data duplication and prevents blowing up memory.

Comment: Thanks where can I learn advanced concepts like these ? I don't think django docs mention such things. I wanna graps as much knowledge as possible. Also where can I contact you ? Please send me your contact would love to work or talk with you my email is `ahtishamshafi9906@gmail.com` looking forward for your reply. :)